# Probar ruta que recibe imagenes con mullter usando supertest y jest

Tags: nodejs, jest, testing

Tengo una api con node.js que recibe imagenes del cliente en formData para ser subidas a google cloud. Estoy aprendiendo testing y me gustaría saber como puedo probar una ruta de este tipo usando supertest. He usado console.logs para verificar, exitosamente, que req.files contiene los archivos/imagenes que espero.Sin embargo, ahora me gustaría hacer un test mas en forma con jest y supertest.

Mi ruta es la siguiente:

```
routes.js

const {Router} = require('express')
const router = Router()
const controller = require('../controller/userPost')
const Multer = require('multer')
const multer = Multer({
    storage : Multer.memoryStorage(),
    //define limits later
})



router.post('/multiple', multer.any(), controller.multiPost)

module.exports = router
```

```
controllers.js
multiPost : async (req, res)=>{
    const resolver = Resolver(res)
    try {
        
        console.log(req.files) //efectivamente hay un arreglo de imagenes
        if(req.files) return res.status(200)

    } catch (error) {
        console.log(error)
    }
},
```

Mi archivo de test es el siguiente

```
userPost.test.js

const app = require('../server')
const request = require('supertest')

describe('userPost/multiple endpoint', ()=>{
    
    it('should return status 200 if images are post to gcs ', ()=>{
        const res = await request(app).post('/userPost/multiple').send({
            
        })
       expect(res.statusCode).toEqual(200)
    })
    

    
})
```

Como puedo simular el envio de imagenes en formData dentro de mi test?

Answer (score 0):

Quízas si cambias el .send({}) de request(app).post('/userPost/multiple').send({}) por .attach("fileFieldName", "test/recourses/testingFile.jpg").

No lo probe, pero eso lei en la documentacion. Espero que te sea útil ^^

Answer (score 0):

creo que debes declarar en `post` tu método enrutador y luego especificar las diferentes opciones, un ejemplo seria algo así:

```
const res = await request(app)
  .post('/userPost/multiple', multiPost) // routes
  .send({'nombre': 'nombre de archivo'})
  .set('Accept', 'application/json')
  .attach('imagen', 'imagen.jpg', {contentType: "image/jpeg"})
  .expect(res.statusCode).toEqual(200)
```